# DataGridView population+modificaion by SQL Server DB View

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I searched StackOverFlow.com for my issue, but could not find any similar/related solution.

I have few tables in SQL Server 2005, and have to make use of those tables in my Winform/C# application which is supposed to be an Admin Application where the Administrator will:-

**1.Add/Edit users**

2.Assign Roles

3.Assign Privileges

4.Zone Assignment

5.Area Assignment

6.Town Assignment

The result of each of these is coming from a minimum of two tables(of SQL Server DB), and this result has to be populated in each individual `DataGridView` of a `TabControl's` each `TabPage`.

The Administrator will first see the results, and then he/she can modify the values via the `SelectedRow` of the `DataGridView`, and in response this modification will be updated in the `Database`(i.e. SQL Server).

Since I am new to programming, my question is that I want to use an 
`SQL Server View`, to get all this stuff done, but haven't used the `View` in connection to the `DataGridView`.

Although I am able to populate the single `DataGridView` from the `SQLServer Binded DataSource`, but this works only for a `single DataGridView`, I need to have the data for all the concerned `DataGridViews` in a single step.

`Can anybody tell me how to do this?`

`If there is any other efficient solution to this, kindly reply.`

**NOTE:I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library, so would not use any In-Line SQL Queries.**

For reference I am attaching the following link with Images.
[link text](http://rapidshare.com/files/399248066/Images.zip.html)

Comment: Any answer to my above question ? I am still waiting for an earliest reply

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, your Binded DataSource has to be from a **single** table in SQL.  Have you tried representing the data differently?  A drill-down to related data instead of showing it all in the same dataset would be your best solution.